# SSRS report shows no data for some parameter values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, drilldown

I have a report with 3 parameters and designed to show % of attendance by main course.

[image: design]

It should be showing data for all the columns but for GCSE column(see image below) report not display any data except 3 rows(shows lot of blanks).Dataset-CourseType

[image: Preview]

[image: Drilldown]

Queries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
PrimaryProgramme, PRPH_Title, PRPH_ML1, 
Section, AgeBand, REGT_Year, Section_Name, 
REGT_Provision_Code, STEN_Student_ID, 
CourseType, Mins_Poss, Mins_Att, 
Mins_Late, TermTimeWeekNo, STUD_Surname, 
Class_Register COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + 
Register_Title COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + ' - ' + 
Register_Day COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + '  ' + CONVERT(char(5),
StartTime, 108) + ' - ' + CONVERT(char(5), EndTime, 108) AS Register
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (REGT_Year = @Year) 
AND (AgeBand IN (@AgeBand)) 
AND (CourseType IN (@CourseType))
    ORDER BY PrimaryProgramme

AgeBand:

SELECT DISTINCT AgeBand
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (REGT_Year = @Year)

    CourseType:
SELECT DISTINCT CourseType
FROM            CurrentAttendance_New
WHERE        (AgeBand IN (@AgeBand))

CurrentAttendance_New(Stored Procedure which is used in datasets):
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.CurrentAttendance_New', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.CurrentAttendance_New; 
--------Create New Table--------------------------------------------------
---Weeks-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
With weeks as 
(select VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year, min(VDC_day_date) as WeekCommence
from sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
where VDC_avail = 'T'
group by VDC_week_no, VDC_cal_year),

---TTWeeks-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
TTWeeks as

(SELECT VDC_Cal_Year as REMSYear, [VDC_week_no] as WholeYearWeekNo, 
WeekCommence
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vdc_cal_year ORDER BY VDC_week_no) as TermTimeWeekNo
FROM weeks)

---Main-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

SELECT DISTINCT   

s.STYR_Primary_Programme AS PrimaryProgramme, 

CASE WHEN s.STYR_Age_end_Aug < 16 THEN '1416' 
WHEN STYR_Age_end_Aug < 19 THEN '1618' ELSE '19+' END AgeBand,

rg.REGT_Year, 

RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML1) AS PRPH_ML1, 

q.GNCD_Description AS [Curriculum Area], 

RTRIM(ph.PRPH_ML2) AS Section, 

q.GNCD_Description AS Section_Name, 

LEFT(q.GNCD_Description, 3) AS Dept, 

RTRIM(rg.REGT_Provision_Code) as REGT_Provision_Code, 

RTRIM(ph.PRPH_Title) as PRPH_Title, 

rm.ROOM_Room_No as RoomNo,

rg.REGT_Student_ID, STEN_Student_ID, STEN_Funding_Stream,  

rs.REGS_Session_No, 

RTRIM(rh.REGH_Class_Register) as Class_Register, 

RTRIM(rh.REGH_Register_Title) as Register_Title, 

CASE WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '1' THEN 'Sunday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '2' THEN 'Monday' 
WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '3' THEN 'Tuesday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '4' THEN 'Wednesday'
WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '5' THEN 'Thursday' WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '6' THEN 'Friday' 
WHEN rh.REGH_Day = '7' THEN 'Saturday' END AS Register_Day, 

rh.[REGH_Start_Time] as StartTime,

rh.[REGH_End_Time] as EndTime,

CASE WHEN (rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '27%' 
OR rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'MA27%' OR
rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE 'FS%') 
THEN 'FunctionalSkill' 
WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '16%' THEN 'GCSE' 
WHEN rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/F%' OR
rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/D%' OR
rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/E%' OR
rg.REGT_Provision_Code LIKE '%/X%' THEN 'Main' 
ELSE 'Addition' END AS CourseType, 

CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') IN ('N', 'Y','X') 
and rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE()
THEN rs.REGS_Duration - ISNULL(rd.REGD_Mins_Late,0) ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Poss, 

CASE WHEN ISNULL(ra.RGAT_Present,'X') = 'Y' AND 
rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
rs.REGS_Duration - rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Att, 

CASE WHEN ra.RGAT_Present = 'Y' AND rs.REGS_Session_Date<GETDATE() THEN 
rd.REGD_Mins_Late ELSE 0 END AS Mins_Late, 

 rl.RGHL_Lecturer_Code AS LectCode, 

RTRIM(PS.PERS_Forename) + ' ' + RTRIM(PS.PERS_Surname) AS LectName, 

RTRIM(PS.PERS_Department_ML) AS LectDepartment,

RTRIM(PS.PERS_Grade) AS LectSection,

rs.[REGS_Session_Date] as Session_Date,

TermTimeWeekNo,

rh.REGH_ISN, ph.PRPH_ISN, st.STUD_Surname, st.STUD_Forename_1, rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark,

rg.REGT_start_date, rg.REGT_End_date, WeekCommence

,FME.STFM_LearnFAMCode as FreeMealsCode,
LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode as LearnerSupportCode,

CASE 
WHEN FME.STFM_LearnFAMCode=1 THEN '14-15 year old learner is eligible for free meals'
WHEN FME.STFM_LearnFAMCode=2 THEN '16-19 year old learner is eligible for and in receipt of free meals'
ELSE 'N/A'
END AS FreeMealsIndicator,

CASE 
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=36   THEN 'Care to Learn (C2L) (EFA funded only)'
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=55   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner member of a vulnerable group (EFA funded only)'  
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=56   THEN '16-19 Bursary Fund - learner awarded discretionary bursary (EFA funded only)' 
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=57   THEN 'Residential support (EFA funded only)'
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=58   THEN '19+ Hardship (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'    
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=59   THEN '20+ Childcare (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)'   
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode=60   THEN 'Residential Access Fund (Skills Funding Agency funded learners only)' 
WHEN LSR.STFM_LearnFAMCode IN (61, 62, 63, 64, 65) THEN 'Unassigned'    
ELSE 'N/A'
END AS Bursary, 



    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='M' THEN 'Male'
    WHEN st.STUD_Gender='F' THEN 'Female'
    END AS Gender, 

    CASE 
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 31 THEN 'White - English / Welsh / Scottish / Northern Irish / British'
    WHEN st.STUD_Ethnicity= 32 THEN 'White - Irish'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 33 THEN 'White - Gypsy or Irish Traveller'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 34 THEN 'White - Any Other White background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 35 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 36 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Black African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 37 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - White and Asian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 38 THEN 'Mixed / Multiple Ethnic group - Any Other Mixed / multiple ethnic background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 39 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Indian'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 40 THEN 'Asian/ Asian British - Pakistani'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 41 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 42 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Chinese'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 43 THEN 'Asian / Asian British - Any other Asian background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 44 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - African'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 45 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Caribbean'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 46 THEN 'Black / African / Caribbean / Black British - Any other Black / African / Caribbean background'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 47 THEN 'Other ethnic group - Arab'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 98 THEN 'Any Other'
    WHEN  st.STUD_Ethnicity= 99 THEN 'Not provided'
    END AS Ethnicity,

    CASE 
    WHEN g.GNUC_Flag_1 = 1 THEN 'Yes'
    else 'No'
    END AS [Looked After Child],

    CASE 
    WHEN sub1.GNUC_Code_4 = 'Y' THEN 'Yes'
    ELSE 'No'
    END AS ALS

    INTO dbo.CurrentAttendance_New   

    FROM        
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGTrgstudt rg

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGSrgsessn rs ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rs.REGS_REGH_ISN  

    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.Vdaily_calender
    ON rs.REGS_Session_Date=VDC_day_date 

    INNER JOIN TTWeeks on rg.REGT_year=TTWeeks.REMSYear
    and VDC_week_no=WholeYearWeekNo AND VDC_cal_year=REMSYear

    INNER  JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.REGHrghdr rh ON rh.REGH_ISN = rg.REGT_REGH_ISN 

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.RGSRSessRoom rgs ON rh.REGH_ISN = rgs.RGSR_REGH_ISN

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.ROOMrooms rm ON rgs.RGSR_Room = rm.ROOM_Room_No 

    left outer JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.RGHLHeadLect AS RL 
    ON REGH_ISN = RL.RGHL_REGH_ISN AND RL.RGHL_Main = 1

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPHProvisionHeader ph ON rg.REGT_Provision_Code = ph.PRPH_Code 

    LEFT outer JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.PERSstaff AS PS 
    ON RL.RGHL_Lecturer_Code = PS.PERS_Staff_Code
    AND RL.RGHL_Main = 1 AND rh.REGH_ISN = RL.RGHL_REGH_ISN 
    AND PS.PERS_Grade = ph.PRPH_ML2


    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes AS ML2 ON ML2.GNCD_General_Code = ph.PRPH_ML2 
    AND ML2.GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2' 

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STEN ON STEN_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID 
    AND STEN_Provision_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code AND
    STEN_Provision_Instance = rg.REGT_Provision_Instance 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM as LSR 
    ON LSR.STFM_Year = STEN_Year 
    AND LSR.STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID and LSR.STFM_LearnFAMType='LSR'

    LEFT OUTER JOIN  sql10.ng.dbo.STFMLearnerFAM as FME 
    ON FME.STFM_Year = STEN_Year 
    AND FME.STFM_Student_ID = STEN_Student_ID and FME.STFM_LearnFAMType='FME'

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.STYRstudentYR s ON s.STYR_Student_ID = rg.REGT_Student_ID 
    AND s.STYR_Year = rg.REGT_Year   

    LEFT JOIN 
    sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom sub1
    ON rg.REGT_Year = SUB1.GNUC_Year 
    AND STYR_ISN = SUB1.GNUC_Entity_ISN
    AND GNUC_Type = 'STYR'

    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     ACYR_College_Year
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.ACYR
    WHERE      (ACYR_ENR_PY_CY_NY = ('CY'))) AS SUB 
    ON REGT_Year = SUB.ACYR_College_Year

    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.STUDStudent st on s.STYR_Student_ID=st.STUD_Student_ID

    LEFT JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.GNUCustom g ON STUD_ISN = g.GNUC_Entity_ISN 
    AND g.GNUC_Type = 'STUD'       


    INNER JOIN sql10.ng.dbo.REGDropin rd ON rg.REGT_REGH_ISN = rd.REGD_REGH_ISN 
    AND rg.REGT_Student_ID = rd.REGD_Student_ID 
    AND rd.REGD_Session_No = rs.REGS_Session_No

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.RGATAttendance ra ON rd.REGD_Attendance_Mark = ra.RGAT_Attendance_Code 

    INNER JOIN
    sql10.ng.dbo.PRPIProvisionInstance AS pit ON pit.PRPI_Code = rg.REGT_Provision_Code 
    and pit.prpi_instance = REGT_Provision_Instance

    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT     GNCD_General_Code, GNCD_Description
    FROM          sql10.ng.dbo.GNCDgncodes
    WHERE      (GNCD_Code_Type = 'M2')) AS q ON q.GNCD_General_Code =  RTrim(ph.PRPH_ML2) 

    END

    GO
```

Comment: You need to edit your question so that you ask a specific question about a specific problem. Which column is blank, and which dataset should populate it? There is too much information in this question.

Comment: @BIDeveloper : Edited, Please see above - see GCSE column and CourseType dataset